# WCF CallBack Object logic

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

In the wcf duplex project I am working on, proxy is created and opened using the following 3 lines:

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new MyCallbackObjectImplementingCallbackContract());

_proxy = new ServiceClient(context);

_proxy.Open();
```

I have a couple of questions here:

1. Lets say my callback contract has just 3 methods(operation contract) and on my callback class, on top of just implementing those 3 I have like 10 more methods.
   I found by debugging on server side when
   `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallbackContract>()` is called
   the object returned has only the methods with attribute 'OperationContract', and not the whole object. What is the magic behind the scenes. Also, is it not a bad design to have bunch of extra(not contract implementations) methods on call back class, if so what impact could it possibly have?
2. `_proxy.open()` metadata says object to transition from the created state into the opened state. I don't quite get what that means?

Answer (score 0):

Question #1: Yes, WCF only looks for methods marked with `OperationContract` attribute. It creates proxies using the old Remoting `RealProxy`/`TransparentProxy` mechanism. Basically, WCF looks for operations in the contract interface, not in a class that implements the interface. It also proxies the contract interface, and not an implementation class.

As for the design question, it depends. As long as the other methods help the operation methods fulfill their contract, there is no problem. But if the other methods implement a different responsibility, then as it sounds, such design violates the single responsibility principle.

Question #2: in WCF, channel proxies inherit `CommunicationObject`. This object is not stateless, it tracks state of communication over the channel. Moreover, it can hold a session on the remote side, which is an expensive and limited resource. For these reasons, communication object should be treated much like database connection: open it, execute the operation, then `Close()` or `Abort()`. You can find more details in [this MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).